# What determines the Angular zone with Socket IO

Tags: angular, sockets, socket.io

I ran into an interesting problem with using SocketIO in my Angular Service.

Case 1: Socket as a property of the service 
When I instantiate the socket on the service class all responses from the socket are done in the angular zone and the UI will update accordingly.

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client/build/index';
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() {
export class MyService {
  private socket = io("localhost:3000")
  
  dealCards(): void {
    this.socket.emit('deal_cards')
  }

  recieveStartingCards(): Observable<GameState> {
    const observable = new Observable<GameState>((observer) => {
      this.socket.on('dealt_cards', (data: GameState) => {
        console.log('IN ZONE', NgZone.isInAngularZone()); // returns true
        observer.next(data));
        return () => this.socket.disconnect();
      });
    });
    return observable;
  }
```

Case 2: Socket as a constant 
When I instantiate the socket as a constant and reference it in the service class. The socket communication occurs outside the angular zone and the UI will only update if you I use `ngZone.run()`

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client/build/index';
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

const socket = io("localhost:3000")

@Injectable() {
export class MyService {
  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}
  private socket = socket
  dealCards(): void {
    this.socket.emit('deal_cards')
  }

  recieveStartingCards(): Observable<GameState> {
    const observable = new Observable<GameState>((observer) => {
      this.socket.on('dealt_cards', (data: GameState) => {
        console.log('IN ZONE', NgZone.isInAngularZone()); // returns false
        observer.next(data));
        return () => this.socket.disconnect();
      });
    });
    return observable;
  }
```

My question is why is socket communication in Case 1 always in the Angular zone and why is socket communication in Case 2 never in the angular zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular zone comes into play at [the stage of bootstrapping](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/fc64fa8e1af9e0bbab40d1b441743744a40c5581/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L339-L345) Angular application.
All Angular services, which are involved in DI(Dependency Injection) system, are instantiated inside this `NgZone.run` call.

In the first case you use socket as a property. It means that it will be instantiated inside service constructor and it happens after bootstrapping process.

In the second case you initialize `io` before bootstrapping app when there is no Angular zone defined.